# Testing image is not working using espresso

Tags: android, android-espresso

I am newbie to use espresso to test android application. 
I tried to test image. while searching in net, i got a link to get the code to test the image.

i have implemented this in my coding. it works well for some of the image verification. but it does not for some of the other images. i do not know why it behaves like this.

for the above code i am getting error like,

```
android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler$AssertionFailedWithCauseError: 'with drawable from resource id: <2131230851>' doesn't match the selected view.
Expected: with drawable from resource id: <2131230851>[o2]
Got: "AppCompatImageView{id=2131296484, res-name=imgSPO2, visibility=VISIBLE, width=150, height=91, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=-1.0}"
```

Herewith i have attached the link, where i get the code to test image.

https://github.com/dbottillo/Blog/blob/espresso_match_imageview/app/src/androidTest/java/com/danielebottillo/blog/config/DrawableMatcher.java

can anyone assist me to overcome from this.

my testing code is,

```
@Test

 public void Test1_Spo2() 

{
    onView(withId(R.id.imgSPO2)).check(matches(withDrawable(R.drawable.o2)));

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The result of `matchesSafely` in the `DrawableMatcher` class is probably false.

Be sure that both images are identical if you use a drawable.xml file.